# Activity whith pitch detect TarsosDSP no restart

Tags: java, android, tarsosdsp

I wrote a guitar tuner in music application. The main  activity launch the tuner when click on button. The tuner works fine. But if I come back to main activity.
The Tuner activity start, but  pitch detection does not.
The thread don't stop for the recorder.

I launch an activity Act_Accordage from the main activity with

```
public void clicAccordage(View v){
        Intent intentAct_Accordage = new Intent(this, Act_Accordeur .class);
    startActivity(intentAct_Accordage);
}
```

Here is my Act_Accordage activity

```
public final AudioDispatcher dispatcher = AudioDispatcherFactory.fromDefaultMicrophone(22050, 2048, 0);
    ....
          dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(new PitchProcessor(PitchEstimationAlgorithm.YIN, 22050, 2048, new PitchDetectionHandler() {

                @Override
                public void handlePitch(PitchDetectionResult pitchDetectionResult,
                                        AudioEvent audioEvent) {
                    final float pitchInHz = pitchDetectionResult.getPitch();
                    if (Logo.interrupted()) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (pitchInHz > -1) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // display name note and cursor ou UI thread
                               textFreqNote.setText(String.valueOf(pitchInHz) + " CREATE "); 
                               Affcurseur(pitchInHz);
                             });
                    }

                }
            }));
             new Thread(dispatcher, "Audio Dispatcher");

    2***/I come back main with  button or backbutton
    public void onclicSetBackMain(View v) {
            Act_Accordeur.this.finish();
            Toast.makeText(Act_Accordeur.this, "Guitare accordée", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
```

Comment: tardos? what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry tarsos dsp library  https://0110.be/releases/TarsosDSP/TarsosDSP-1.6/TarsosDSP-1.6-Readme.html

Answer (score 0):

Use dispatcher.stop(); to stop the Audio Dispatcher thread.It took me a long time in the official documentation but it was worth it.